# Le sens et le registre social de la phrase « au diable vauvert » ?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Dans « Total Kheops » par Jean-Claude Izzo on trouve la phrase suivante:

- Vé ! Z'aurez bien un peu de temps pour aller la voir, non ? C'est quand même pas au diable vauvert !

Dans ce cadre le sens général du morceau en total est plus ou moins clair, mais « au diable vauvert », qu'est-ce que ça signifie ?

Comment: http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/au-diable-vauvert.php     /   https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/origines/expression-au-diable-vauvert/

Answer (score 2):

D'après [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vauvert) et [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=au%20diable%20vauvert&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cau%20diable%20vauvert%3B%2Cc0), même si diverses expressions contenant *diable Vauvert(d)* sont attestées depuis 1440, l'expression *aller au diable vauvert*, elle, n'apparaît qu'au milieu du 19e siècle. Cette expression signifie *aller très loin*. TLFi explique:

> 1842 aller au diable Vauvert. De Vauvert, nom d'un château situé près de Gentilly. Selon Sainte-Foix (Essais sur Paris), le château aurait été convoité par les Chartreux propriétaires d'un château voisin, qui pour inciter le roi Louis IX à leur en faire la donation, organisèrent des apparitions de diables, et ainsi en vinrent à leur fin.

Pour ce qui est du registre de langue, l'expression elle-même, rare, est probablement neutre, mais la phrase qui la précède dans l'OP est assez vulgaire.

Comment: Le phrase qui précède n'a pas pour objectif de choquer. Je ne dirais donc pas qu'elle est vulgaire mais que c'est juste du langage familier.